# $T$ has $(x-1)^4$ as its characteristic polynomial then what is the largest possible dimension of the centraliser of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, contest-math

> Q.If $ I\neq T\in M_{4}(\mathbb{C})$ has $(x-1)^4$ as its characteristic
>   polynomial then what is the largest possible dimension of the
>   centraliser of $T$ in $M_{4}(\mathbb{C})$.$(=$the space of all
>   matrices that commute with $T)?$

I am looking for a hint. I know that $T$ is not diagonalizable. But how should I proceed further?

Comment: I suppose it could have only one off-diagonal entry —

Comment: Note that $T$ and $T-I$ have the same centralizer, so you can actually assume that the characteristic polynomial is $x^4$, i..e $T$ is nilpotent. This might make it easier to just manually check the centralizer of each possible Jordan form.

Comment: Do you know how to compute centralizers of Jordan forms?

Answer (score 0):

Taking cue from ${\color{blue}{ MooS}}$ the possible jordan forms are:

$\begin{bmatrix}0\,0\,0\,0\\0\,0\,0\,0\\0\,0\,0\,0\\0\,0\,0\,0\end{bmatrix}$, 
$\begin{bmatrix}0\,1\,0\,0\\0\,0\,0\,0\\0\,0\,0\,0\\0\,0\,0\,0\end{bmatrix}$,
$\begin{bmatrix}0\,1\,0\,0\\0\,0\,0\,0\\0\,0\,0\,1\\0\,0\,0\,0\end{bmatrix}$,
$\begin{bmatrix}0\,1\,0\,0\\0\,0\,1\,0\\0\,0\,0\,0\\0\,0\,0\,0\end{bmatrix}$,
$\begin{bmatrix}0\,1\,0\,0\\0\,0\,1\,0\\0\,0\,0\,1\\0\,0\,0\,0\end{bmatrix}$.

The dimensions of centralizers of the above matrices are 16,15,14,13. Thus the dimension of the largest possible centralizer of T is 13. Am I correct?

Comment: Largest of them is 15 @YadatiKiran isn't it???

Comment: But would matrix of dimension 15 satisfy $ST=TS$ with $T$ having the last jordan form ??

Comment: But how do you know it does not?? @YadatiKiran